# Как скопировать данные с HDD другого ПК

Tags: windows, hdd

я вынужден приобрести новый ноутбук для работы из-за поломки основного, где на HDD лежит папка с проектом (сайтом). у ноутбуков HDD диски одинаковые.

как я могу скопировать файлы со сломанного ноутбука в новый без финансовых трат ? можете посоветовать оптимальные выходы без летальных исходов для моей ситуации ?

Comment: если ноут не стартует и проблема не в диске, то разобрать, снять диск и подключить к другому компу, затем скопировать данные.

Comment: @teran это два разных ноутбука (acer и sony). Система не стартанет. Поломка в хабе и видео чипе на плате

Comment: так я вам и не говорил, подключить вообще к ноутбуку, тем более не предлагал с нее загружаться. Подключите к ПК если есть возможность, там куда проще подобраться к шлейфам. Если нет ПК, то скрывайте второй ноут, и подключайте как второй винт вместо хдд, или если есть место под второй винт. Возможно, новый новый ноутывскрывать не стоит,если там вдруг какие-то пломбы есть, так что ищите ПК, это куда проще.

Comment: Да просто USB-SATA переходник добыть, зачем сразу вскрывать)

Comment: @andreymal я в первую очередь рассматриваю без финансов решение проблемы.

Comment: @teran второй ноут не работает, поэтому я приобрёл новый, кажется написал об этом. ПК тоже нет. есть только один новый ноутбук + iPhone (ну мало ли)

Comment: вам 10 лет что ли? начните с того чтобы диск снять. потом думайте куда воткнуть. у вас 3 варианта предложено. в свой ноут вторым винтом, в чужой комп, купить/найти провод юсб

Comment: @teran жалко минус вам поставить нельзя. написано на русском языке: ПК нет, без финансовых трат. Остаётся только один вариант - «вторым винтом», но это не является возможным, т.к место для диска одно. думаю воткну в розетку, как раз для 10ти летнего разума это идейная идея. спасибо!

Comment: вы живете изолированно? нет никаких друзей с ПК, на работе, учебе, у родственников? я ведь написал "чужой ПК".

Comment: можете вставить в новый ноут  вместо основного диска. загрузиться с большой флешки и скопировать  на нее же файлы. Если правда у вас и флешки нет, то хз что вам еще предложить.

Comment: @teran не заметил «чужой». кстати, да. у меня есть линукс на флэшка, попробую, спасибо, что напомнили

Comment: @teran красава)